# Forbidden Cannot serve request to /content/dam/ in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

Tags: adobe, aem

i'm new in ADOBE CQ5, i have configure AEM successfully now, i'm creating demo site using CRXDe, i create my web site folder in following directory :

```
/apps/mywebsite
```

and also create my website directory in Tools/Design/MyWebsite

i want to add static css class using DAM i'm using this path
 using http://localhost:4502/content/dam/ , then it's give an error:

```
Forbidden
Cannot serve request to /content/dam/inorg.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
```

here i want to provide access using WebDAV, i'm following this article:

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/content/webdav-access.html

i try it but couldn't fix this issue, can anyone suggest me what i'm missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read article you posted link to more thoroughly. As I understand, you are trying to open this url in the browser, but it's not the right way. You should connect to server in your filemanager (in unix systems) or go to "My Network Places" and add Network Place (in Win XP). Then you would be able to provide credentials (usually admin/admin on local env) and web-dav connection will be established.

Also I would suggest connect simply to  "localhost:4502" to avoid errors with path interpretation (which I have on my ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the DAM with the following URL: http://localhost:4502/damadmin#/content/dam/content
The process of uploading resources isn't very intuitive. 
Basically, you select create new file and this option lets you upload a file from anywhere in on filesystem.
Hope this helps.